# Why do some faces not emit hair?

Tags: particles, edit-mode

I am trying to create a bit of a fuzz feeling to my object. However, when I want to add Hair by using the Particle system, the hair are not distributed equally over the faces, as you can see in the picture below.

How can I make sure the faces have equal amounts of hair?

Is the problem that my mesh does not have the same dimensions of faces?

Here is the file: [image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It may be pure hasard, maybe in the Particles > Hair panel > Emission > Source disable Random Order, or under Emission change the Seed value.

Comment: Check your faces orientation

Comment: @moonboots tried both - does not make a difference.

Comment: @Emir. Checked and everything is blue. I also recalculated Normals so that was also not the issue.

Comment: I also cannot subdivide the side faces to create a more denser mesh.

Comment: could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: I have added the file!

Answer (score 1):

Check this, as if not the generated geometry will not be properly taken into account:

[image]

Concretely, the issue is most likely due to ngons, that you should avoid.